# Azure DevOps to connect VM and Access Resources (Application)

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-devops, virtual-machine

I have Rapise Automation tool inside Windows VM, I would to access/invoke that application and read generated output files;

I have a powershell script which can run on Windows powershell and invoke Rapise application (local) and do the same, what I want.

Someone, please help me to connect to VM from Azure DevOps tasks.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Agents communication with Azure Pipelines. When you use the agent to deploy artifacts to a set of servers, it must have "line of sight" connectivity to those servers. The Microsoft-hosted agent pools, by default, have connectivity to Azure websites and servers running in Azure.

If your on-premises environments do not have connectivity to a Microsoft-hosted agent pool (which is typically the case due to intermediate firewalls), you'll need to manually configure a self-hosted agent on on-premises computer(s). The agents must have connectivity to the target on-premises environments, and access to the Internet to connect to Azure Pipelines or Team Foundation Server, as shown in the following schematic.

Once you have the agent configured , you can leverage the tasks to run PowerShell on target machines with the Release pipeline task gallery.

[image]

[Additional documentation reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops)

Hope this helps.